# Accessing SecretKeys from a diffrent region in cloudformation aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a secret key in us-east-1 region in aws and I want to reference its arn in a stack in diffrent region, like this :
[image]
when !Ref SecretKeys is a parameter and I pass it the arn of the SecretKey

```
arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:########:secret:########
```

and this is what I get when I run the stack:
[image]